# setText is throwing nullpointerexception when trying to display data in onPostExecute method

Tags: android

I'm trying to get response from servlet and display it on emulator. Able to get response but when I'm trying to display response on screen, setText is throwing null pointer exception. Unable to figure out the cause. I'm pretty new to android, kindly help me.

package com.example.httptest;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import com.demo.parser.XmlParser;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String url = "http://192.168.3.140:8080/HttpServlet/TestServlet";
    //public static final String url = "http://192.168.3.228/capture/employeeList.xml";
    String output = null;
    TextView outpuText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void invokeServlet(View view){
        AsyncTest test = new AsyncTest();
        System.out.println("URL--------------"+url);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        test.execute(new String[] { url });
    }

    private class AsyncTest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String output = null;

            for(String url :urls){
                System.out.println("url1 "+url);
                output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
                System.out.println("output----------"+output);

                /*EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.output);

                 text.setText(output);

                */

            }

            return output;
        }

         private String getOutputFromUrl(String url) {
             System.out.println("in hereeeeeeeeeee");

                try {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    System.out.println("output1 "+output);
                   // XmlParser.XMLfromString(output);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return output;
            }


         protected void onPostExecute(String output){

             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             outpuText.setText(output);


             setContentView(outpuText);
         }



    }

}
```

Comment: show us a result of Log.d("output", output); ..... can you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by adding following step in onCreate method,

outpuText = new TextView(this);

Thanks for your time guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Add `outpuText=(TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.textId);` in onCreate method after setContentView() will help you out.

Dont forget to remove setContentView() from postExecute().

Comment: r u getting anything in catch block. If u know debugging try to debug, I have a strong feeling something goes wrong in try block and output is not getting any thing. Otherwise try putting Log.i("Exception","Exception_Name "); in each exception with exception name to check whether any exception is caught or not.

And also remove unnecessary setContentView

Comment: Issue resolved by adding following step in onCreate method,


outpuText = new TextView(this);

Thanks for your time guys!!

Answer (score 0):

1) Give refernce to outputText. i mean 
  outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); in onCreate method.

2) remove setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); in onPostExecute(String output).

Comment: The reason it is throwing nullPointerException is because you are setting a layout and then without creating a reference from that layout to ouputText textview you are setting a value(Text) to it.

Comment: edit the post with what you have done and also by adding the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

try this it solved your problem

```
 outpuText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
```

where textviewid  is your textview id

Comment: before  outpuText.setText(output);

Comment: @user1716809 clean application and after rebuilding run again

Comment: and replace outpuText.setText(output);  to outpuText.setText(""+output);